# How to submit a web form using console app

Tags: c#, webforms

There is a web application, that has a login. After logging in, there is a form that opens in a popup. I have the login access, but I would like to programmatically submit this form, using a console app.

I tried the following code (right inside the main function). The program executes without any error, but no data is saved in the application.

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/Request");
string postData = "Key=LogDetails&billHours=112";
byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = send.Length;
Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
sout.Flush();
sout.Close();
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Maybe this is not the right way to submit a form that has a login. Is that correct.

How can I check if I'm posting to the correct URL and all the data is being passed in the right way.

**Form Markup:** https://jsfiddle.net/semumwwg/1/

**Response in returnValue:**

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript"> var undefined;
if(typeof(opener) == "undefined" || opener == undefined){ window.top.location="/Request?Key=login&ST=Y&childProcessId=r92FySfS92Bs92BP9CTzQKlRmwOw93D93D";}
else{try{tmp = window.opener.name;window.close();opener.top.location='/Request?Key=login&ST=Y&childProcessId=r92FySfS92Bs92BP9CTzQKlRmwOw93D93D';}catch(exception){top.location='/Request?Key=login&ST=Y&childProcessId=r92FySfS92Bs92BP9CTzQKlRmwOw93D93D';}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the response from the server?

Comment: Can you submit the HTML of your web form

Comment: @Gusman Yes there is a reply, but I'm not sure how or what to analyse from it. It is actually html with <script> in it

Comment: @ammcom You  want me to paste the markup of the form?

Comment: @Qwerty Analyze the response, there must be some type of message which may help you understand what's wrong.

Comment: Yes Paste it here

Comment: @ammcom I have updated the question. Please have a look.